# Accessing SQL Server remotely using Windows Authentication

Tags: sql-server, database-connection, ssms, windows-authentication, remote-access

I have setup SQLExpress on a Windows 10 PC and trying to access it via another PC.

I also configured my setup using [this](https://knowledgebase.apexsql.com/configure-remote-access-connect-remote-sql-server-instance-apexsql-tools/) guide.

I was able to connect using SQL Server Authentication.
However, when I tried connecting using Windows Authentication, I received the following message:

> The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with integrated authentication.

Is there a step I might have missed?

Comment: Make an effort. You provide no context and no one knows anything about your network topology. That error (just search on the first part of the message) has been discussed MANY times. Review those discussions to help understand the problem and how to address it (or at least what information others need to help you).

Answer (score 0):

You may need to launch your SSMS under a different set of credentials (runas) in order for it to connect via windows authentication. One way to do this is to create a simple batch file (or shortcut) to do so.

Create a batch file on your desktop and name it something like:

```
AltSsms.bat
```

Add the following line to the **AltSsms.bat** file:

```
runas.exe /netonly /user:{domain}\{username} "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18\Common7\IDE\Ssms.exe"
```

Be sure to replace `{domain}` and `{username}` with the actual values expected by the remote computer, and provide the full path to your local SSMS installation. I've provided my SSMS path for reference.

Save the updates to the batch file and then double-click it to open it. You should be prompted to enter the password for the `{domain}\{username}` you specified in the batch file.

Once SSMS loads (and assuming you've entered proper credentials), attempt to connect to the SQL Server instance with Windows Authentication. I've had to do this with several SSIS setups.

Comment: Thanks. I tried this, however ran into the same issues. Even if this worked, it is probably not ideal as I was prompted for a pw before SSMS could open, and had to reenter the server name every time it loaded. I would also like to be able to connect using Excel as well. Btw, I used {PC name}\{username}, I am unfamiliar with setting up domain and whether it can be setup on a Windows 10 PC.

Comment: Well, that's a bummer. It's the only way I could ever get SSMS able to connect to another PC that required WA. It's not ideal, but if you're looking beyond SSMS anyway, it's not a problem solver. It's possible Windows Firewall may be blocking your attempts. Also, PCName\Username is correct when no domain controller is in effect.